# Running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS: How to Graphically Create A Bootable USB Windows 10 Flash Drive?

Tags: boot, usb, 20.04, flash

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I want to create a Windows 10 bootable USB for someone, but when I tried the different ways to get Woe USB running, it seems like it's not yet supported on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Is there another GUI tool that runs on Ubuntu that flashes Windows 10?

- MultiWriter just resulted in "no bootable disk" upon starting PC.
- WoeUSB keeps giving errors upon installing.
- Etcher does not support it, but even after I attempted to do so, "no bootable disk found."

I am not looking for terminal-based solutions, rather GUI applications to flash Windows, and I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: You can try with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). The current version, 12.5.7, can create a Windows installer to a USB drive. It works in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and with the current Windows iso files.

Comment: @sudodus, you're fantastic! mkusb worked wonders. Thanks a million.

Comment: @MikeyKuplevatsky, You are welcome, I'm glad that I could help you :-)